# Getting error while executing 'execute immediate ' query

Tags: oracle

I have to insert data of one table to another one. I have create a procedure for.
In procedure one varchar2 variable 
Code is below-

```
create or replace procedure proc_OneTimeLoad

 as
  query varchar2(5000);

begin

  OneTimeLoad_query := 'INSERT INTO trgt_table
              (Originterminal,
               Destinationterminal,
               Scheduledepartdate,
               Scheduledeparttime,
               Runtypenbr,
               DOW,
               Sched_Slip_Arr_Tm,
               DAY,
               Sched_Arr_Tm,
               Drivercode,
               Puprunflag,
               Sched_Cd,
               Status_Cd)

             SELECT Orgn_Term_Cd,
   Dest_Term_Cd,
   sysdate,
   Sched_Dep_Tm,
   Run_Nbr,
   DOW,
   to_date(
   LPAD(nvl(substr(tn.Sched_Slip_Arr_Tm,1,length(Sched_Slip_Arr_Tm)- 2),0),2,0)
   ||'''':''''||
   RPAD(nvl(TRUNC(TO_NUMBER(substr(Sched_Slip_Arr_Tm,3,length(Sched_Slip_Arr_Tm) - 2)) * .60,0),0),2,0)      
   ||'''':00''''
   ,''''HH24:MI:SS'''')
   as Sched_Slip_Arr_Tm,
   Day,
   to_date(
   LPAD(nvl(substr(tn.sched_arr_tm,1,length(sched_arr_tm)- 2),0),2,0)
   ||'''':''''||
   RPAD(nvl(TRUNC(TO_NUMBER(substr(sched_arr_tm,3,length(sched_arr_tm) - 2)) * .60,0),0),2,0)      
   ||'''':00''''
   ,''''HH24:MI:SS'''') 
   as Sched_Arr_Tm,
   Drvr_Cd,
   Pup_Run_Flg,
   ''''B'''',
   ''''1P''''
FROM src_table tn
WHERE tn.dow = to_char(sysdate - 1, ''''D'''')
AND tn.sched_dep_tm between
       TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(sysdate, ''''HH24:MI:SS''''), 1, 2) ||
                 TRUNC(SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(sysdate, ''''HH24:MI:SS''''), 4, 2) * 100/60,0)) 
  AND
       TO_NUMBER(TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(sysdate, ''''HH24:MI:SS''''), 1, 2)) + 12 ||
                 TRUNC(SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(sysdate, '''' HH24 :MI :SS ''''), 4, 2) * 100 / 60, 0))';

  execute immediate query;


  dbms_output.put_line(' Data loaded successfully');

end;
```

Here i am getting error while executing this procedure 'Missing right parenthesis. I think there is some problem of [']. 
I want to user' ' in query to concatenate string.
just like for getting time

**where time=to_date(HH||':'||mi||':'||ss,''HH24:MI:SS')**

Please help me somebody.

Comment: When you're stuck you should simplify your problem as much as possible.  That process will usually solve the problem for you.  In this case, you are using 4 quotation marks when you should use 2.  Or to simplify things even more, use the [alternative quoting mechanism](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements003.htm#i42617).  For example, `query := q'!select date '2000-01-01' ...!'`.  Also, you should accept some of the answers to your previous questions, to let other people know the answer is correct.

Comment: if i am using only '' then getting error that these are not valid bind variables.

Comment: @user1965381 in your sql i see no reason for dynamic SQL here as you dont appear to be altering the string at all. but all of your quotes are doubled up e.g. `||'''':''''||` should be `||'':''||` etc.

Answer (score 2):

your dynamic SQL seems escaped too much. i.e. it looks more correct as:

```
   OneTimeLoad_query := 'INSERT INTO trgt_table
               (Originterminal,
                Destinationterminal,
                Scheduledepartdate,
                Scheduledeparttime,
                Runtypenbr,
                DOW,
                Sched_Slip_Arr_Tm,
                DAY,
                Sched_Arr_Tm,
                Drivercode,
                Puprunflag,
                Sched_Cd,
                Status_Cd)    
              SELECT Orgn_Term_Cd,
    Dest_Term_Cd,
    sysdate,
    Sched_Dep_Tm,
    Run_Nbr,
    DOW,
    to_date(
    LPAD(nvl(substr(tn.Sched_Slip_Arr_Tm,1,length(Sched_Slip_Arr_Tm)- 2),0),2,0)
    ||'':''||
    RPAD(nvl(TRUNC(TO_NUMBER(substr(Sched_Slip_Arr_Tm,3,length(Sched_Slip_Arr_Tm) - 2)) * .60,0),0),2,0)
    ||'':00''
    ,''HH24:MI:SS'')
    as Sched_Slip_Arr_Tm,
    Day,
    to_date(
    LPAD(nvl(substr(tn.sched_arr_tm,1,length(sched_arr_tm)- 2),0),2,0)
    ||'':''||
    RPAD(nvl(TRUNC(TO_NUMBER(substr(sched_arr_tm,3,length(sched_arr_tm) - 2)) * .60,0),0),2,0)
    ||'':00''
    ,''HH24:MI:SS'')
    as Sched_Arr_Tm,
    Drvr_Cd,
    Pup_Run_Flg,
    ''B'',
    ''1P''
 FROM src_table tn
 WHERE tn.dow = to_char(sysdate - 1, ''D'')
 AND tn.sched_dep_tm between
        TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(sysdate, ''HH24:MI:SS''), 1, 2) ||
                  TRUNC(SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(sysdate, ''HH24:MI:SS''), 4, 2) * 100/60,0))
   AND
        TO_NUMBER(TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(sysdate, ''HH24:MI:SS''), 1, 2)) + 12 ||
                  TRUNC(SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(sysdate, ''HH24:MI:SS ''), 4, 2) * 100 / 60, 0))';

   execute immediate OneTimeLoad_query;
```

although given your example i don't see why static SQL isn't used here, as your not dynamically building the SQL. ie why don't you just fire:

```
INSERT INTO trgt_table
              (Originterminal,
               Destinationterminal,
               Scheduledepartdate,
               Scheduledeparttime,
               Runtypenbr,
               DOW,
               Sched_Slip_Arr_Tm,
               DAY,
               Sched_Arr_Tm,
               Drivercode,
               Puprunflag,
               Sched_Cd,
               Status_Cd)
             SELECT Orgn_Term_Cd,
   Dest_Term_Cd,
   sysdate,
   Sched_Dep_Tm,
   Run_Nbr,
   DOW,
   to_date(
   LPAD(nvl(substr(tn.Sched_Slip_Arr_Tm,1,length(Sched_Slip_Arr_Tm)- 2),0),2,0)
   ||':'||
   RPAD(nvl(TRUNC(TO_NUMBER(substr(Sched_Slip_Arr_Tm,3,length(Sched_Slip_Arr_Tm) - 2)) * .60,0),0),2,0)
   ||':00'
   ,'HH24:MI:SS')
   as Sched_Slip_Arr_Tm,
   Day,
   to_date(
   LPAD(nvl(substr(tn.sched_arr_tm,1,length(sched_arr_tm)- 2),0),2,0)
   ||':'||
   RPAD(nvl(TRUNC(TO_NUMBER(substr(sched_arr_tm,3,length(sched_arr_tm) - 2)) * .60,0),0),2,0)
   ||':00'
   ,'HH24:MI:SS')
   as Sched_Arr_Tm,
   Drvr_Cd,
   Pup_Run_Flg,
   'B',
   '1P'
FROM src_table tn
WHERE tn.dow = to_char(sysdate - 1, 'D')
AND tn.sched_dep_tm between
       TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'HH24:MI:SS'), 1, 2) ||
                 TRUNC(SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'HH24:MI:SS'), 4, 2) * 100/60,0))
  AND
       TO_NUMBER(TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'HH24:MI:SS'), 1, 2)) + 12 ||
                 TRUNC(SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'HH24:MI:SS '), 4, 2) * 100 / 60, 0))
```